# Does a US Citizen need a visa to enter as a tourist to the UK for 6 months?

Tags: visas, uk, us-citizens

Everything I've seen points to no (and I would love that to be true since applying for a visa online costs money) but I'm worried about getting refused due to the length of time I wish to stay, which is 6 months.

I went to university in the UK on a Tier 4 visa, but have never just been a tourist which is what I would like to do now. Since graduating, I have started working but am underwhelmed and would love to travel again. My original plan was Australia but now I would like to see the rest of the UK as well beforehand.

If I arrived with the following, would I be refused entry simply for not applying online?: an approved Australian work & holiday visa, a mini itinerary, bank statements for the last 6 months.

Comment: 6 months is not tourism, it's immigration. If you go for 6 months, immigration officers will interpret that as planning to take up residence, getting a job or taking up studies. All of which requires a visa.

Comment: @jwenting: US citizens are given a 6-month permit automatically when entering the UK. Therefore I don't think 6 months makes them think you're immigrating.

Answer (score 10):

The US is a non-visa national country which means you do not have to apply for entry clearance (visa) before you arrive.  Instead, you have a landing interview with an Immigration Officer at the port.  If your landing interview is successful, you will get 6 months leave to enter.

The landing interview will cover the points listed in Appendix V of the Immigration Rules.   You would be advised to bring supporting evidence with you.  The ones you listed will help.  Because you were previously here on a T4, you should expect a more intensive landing interview because it may look like you are attempting to build up a life in the UK or look for work or possibly break the rules.

Genuine visitors do not stay for a long time because they have a life some place else.  You should be prepared to explain how you will support yourself during your visit.

You can find Appendix V of the rules [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/449641/20150803_Immigration_Rules_-_Appendix_V.pdf).

Based upon what you wrote, a solid understanding of items V 4.2 is advised, particularly 'successive visits'...