# I have a 16 hour layover in Heathrow London

Tags: visas, uk, layovers, lhr

I'm travelling from the USA to Madeira Portugal and I have a layover for 16 hours. I was wondering if I need a Visa in order to stay the night in a hotel at the airport in terminal 4? This is the first time I'm travelling international so would like some advice also am I allowed to do a little sight seeing while I'm there without a visa?

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36168/does-a-us-citizen-need-a-visa-to-enter-as-a-tourist-to-the-uk-for-6-months/36171#36171

Answer (score 2):

The situation you have described, and assuming you are travelling on a US passport is covered by paragraph 23A of the Immigration Rules, which says in part...

> 23A. A person who is not a visa national and who is seeking leave to
>   enter on arrival in the United Kingdom for a period not exceeding 6
>   months for a purpose for which prior entry clearance is not required
>   under these Rules may be granted such leave, for a period not
>   exceeding 6 months.

The link for this https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/365580/20141020_Immigration_Rules.pdf

Determining whether or not you are a so-called 'visa national' is a matter of looking for your country in the list.

> 1. Subject to paragraph 2 below, the following persons need a visa for the United Kingdom: (a) Nationals or citizens of the following
>      countries or territorial entities:

(followed by a long list of countries)

The US is not on the list and so US citizens are ok to enter on the basis of a successful landing interview.

The link for this is https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/306590/Immigration_Rules_-_Appendix_1.pdf

Finally, as a US citizen, you'll have a landing interview which will cover Paragraph 41 of the Immigration Rules. This says in part...

> 41. The requirements to be met by a person seeking leave to enter the United Kingdom as a  general visitor are that he:

The link for this is https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/307256/20140317_Immigration_Rules_-_Part_2.pdf

The 'formal' and 'official' visa that you get is called '**Limited Leave to Enter**', and is issued according to Paragraph 42 of the rules (same link).  It is a visa and subject to all the various rules about overstaying, working, and so on.

All links in this answer lead to the UK Government's site so they can be taken as authoritative. Note that SOME of these rules, especially Paragraph 41, will change between now and April 2015.

Comment: Why the negative vote? +1 from me…

Answer (score 1):

Not if you're traveling with a US passport. Americans can get their visa issued upon arrival in the UK.

https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/transit

Comment: Can you provide a link as evidence? It's goo for people to have a reference to point to, rather than 'someone on the internet' ;)

Comment: [" If you are coming to the United Kingdom for any purpose **other than a tourist or business visit of less than six months in duration**, you must have a visa prior to your arrival at a UK port of entry."](http://london.usembassy.gov/cons_new/acs/scs/entry_in_to_the_uk.html)

Comment: @MarkMayo, it's stated explicitly in the rules.

Comment: Yes but clearly the OP doesn't know where said rules are, which is why a link is handy.

Comment: @MarkMayo, in that case, I'll add an answer too...

Comment: @Malvolio, the information on that page is out-of-date

Comment: @GayotFow I don't know where to find the rules either. Is that an official thing, or do you two just pass it back and forth on a napkin?

Comment: The link indicates that “You won’t need a visa to come to the UK”, not that you would get a visa on arrival…

Comment: Now I remember why only 5 people contribute to travel stackoverflow.

Comment: @StephenP. Don't know what you're on about. The link to the US embassy is out-of-date full stop. There is no such agency called UKBA. The link in your answer refers to a transit visa, it's current but they won't issue a transit visa to a non visa national unless they have a criminal record. Not clear what you're on about at all.

Comment: @StephenP. all I meant is that it's handy to have links. While your answer is by all means likely accurate (I upvoted), it's simply that it helps to link to a site if possible. We've had some answers sans links on here in the past that were wrong and could potentially get people in hot water, so it's useful to back them up.  We're generally more accepting than say skeptics, who want documentation for everything, while a lot of our answers come anecdotally as well.

Comment: The answer is not accurate and mixes several things up, is there any SE site where that's encouraged? I have seen some where answers get summarily deleted or happily voted down, you just received some comments, not even a single down-vote!